# Is it possible to deprecate an input parameter on GraphQL query?

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I want to deprecate an input parameter that's no longer used. But I **do not get** a deprecated warning in GraphQL doc.

```
extend type Query {
    getSomething(
       param1: String!, 
       param2: String @deprecated(reason: "param2 is no longer used")
    ): String!
}
```